# How to Use where Clause in Count function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am having Following data in table

```
Country State RequestStatus
India   MP        0
India  MP         1
Usa    At         0
Usa    At          0
```

How to get All the Completed, Pending and total request with Country and state wise grouped in MSSql query.

```
0: Pendint
1: Complete
```

Out put should be something like below

```
Country State Total Pending Complete
India    MP    2     1        1
USA      At    2     2        0
```

Comment: Pls provide example output

Comment: I've updated m y code example below due to your last edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Country,State , COUNT(* ) AS Total 
,SUM(CASE WHEN RequestStatus = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Pending 
,SUM(CASE WHEN RequestStatus = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Complete 
FROM @Test T 
GROUP BY Country,State
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
select country, [state], 
count(*) as Total, 
sum(case when requeststatus = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as Pending, 
sum(case when requeststatus = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Complete
from tbl
group by country, [state]
```

We first group by the country and state to get aggregated data. Then, for calculating the total based on specific condition, we use `case` construct to filter out the matching records. e.g. If we want to get only the Pending Requests, we only increment the counter when `requeststatus = 0`.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/GGBWYI4404)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PIVOT` as an example.

```
CREATE TABLE #yourTable(Country nvarchar(10), State nvarchar(5), RequestStatus bit)

INSERT INTO #yourTable(Country, State, RequestStatus)
VALUES(N'India', N'MP', 0), (N'India', N'MP', 1)

SELECT *
FROM #yourTable
PIVOT (
    COUNT(State)
    FOR RequestStatus IN([0],[1])
) as PVT

DROP TABLE #yourTable
```

But this depends mainly on your expected result. Maybe you'll want to count MP and group id by RequestStatus instead. But I'm not sure as you haven't provided an example output for this.